# Are there any standards for APIs (like EDI), like message for placing order, retrieving prices, stocs, etc?

Tags: rest, api-design, erp, edi, edifact

I'm about to design a (REST) API for a custom ERP solution. The API will then be connected to some EDI solution.

Are there some standards, common message format for contracts like placing orders, retrieving product catalog, prices, stocks, etc, or am I completely on my own?

Comment: For EDI, yes.  For an API that you're developing for a custom ERP, I can't think of any.  I was thinking about industry/vertical specific standards like RosettaNet, but that's more of an EDI implementation.  Good thing about it: you have cart blanche.  Bad thing: you have cart blanche.  It's why EDI will likely never die, especially for as many things that tried to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

So there isn't a widespread business message format tied to REST services in particular. However, as they work well with XML, I would recommend using [UBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Business_Language). It's an open standard and it's widely used in multiple international networks and it covers all typical message types so you shouldn't struggle to connect to EDI solutions using it.

Answer (score 1):

cXML is a common standard, the standard is used by quite a few vendors like Coupa, SAP Ariba, Oracle, Business central amongst others
Routing / partners are defined in the document header to ensure correct handling
The API has a post method which acknowledges or rejects depending on content in the cXML document received
The cXML standard includes status reponse message wich should be returned from the API
The API should have a GET method which returns the API status in a response message
You can find more information at https://xml.cxml.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs defined as standard for Order To Cash cycle. However, there are multiple providers like ezcom who would have published such APIs for their software.
On the other hand, for the logistics industry SSC has published the APIs already.